# Transform JSON object to nested value, label, children

Tags: javascript, mapping, reduce

I have the following JSON:

```js
{
  "notebook": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "macbook",
        "value": "MacBook"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2021",
        "value": "2021"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "2021 Pro",
        "value": "2021 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "e590",
        "value": "E590"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "p1",
        "value": "P1"
      }]
    }
  ],
  "smartphone": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "11pro",
        "value": "11 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2020",
        "value": "2020"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "12",
        "value": "12"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

My desired structure is:

```html
[
  {
    value: "notebook",
    label: "Notebook",
    children: [
      {
        value: "apple",
        label: "Apple",
        children: [
          {
            value: "macbook",
            label: "MacBook",
            children: [
              {
                value: "2021pro",
                label: "2021 Pro",
              },
              {
                value: "2019",
                label: "2019",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        value: "ibm",
        label: "IBM",
        children: [
          {
            value: "thinkpad",
            label: "Thinkpad",
            children: [
              {
                value: "e590",
                label: "E590",
              },
              {
                value: "p1",
                label: "P1",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        value: "lenovo",
        label: "Lenovo",
        children: [
          {
            value: "thinkpad",
            label: "Thinkpad",
            children: [
              {
                value: "e590",
                label: "E590",
              },
              {
                value: "p1",
                label: "P1",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: "Smartphone",
    label: "Smartphone",
    children: [
      {
        value: "apple",
        label: "Apple",
        children: [
          {
            value: "iphone",
            label: "IPHONE",
            children: [
              {
                value: "11pro",
                label: "11 Pro",
              },
              {
                value: "12",
                label: "12",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

How can this be done ?

**Looking for a solution with Array.prototype.reduce / Array.prototype.map**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach. It uses built-in array function like `reduce`, `filter`, `map`.

```
const out = Object.values(input).map(e => {
    const _get = key => ({ [key]: e.map(m => [...m[key]]).flat()
        .filter((m, i, a) => !a.slice(i + 1).find(c => c.key === m.key)) });
    const _join = (parent, children) => {
        const [pkey, ckey] = [Object.keys(parent)[0], Object.keys(children)[0]];
        return {
            [pkey]: parent[pkey].map(p => ({ value: p.key, label: p.value,
                    children: e.reduce((o, m) =>
                        o.concat(m[pkey].find(pp => pp.key === p.key) ?
                            children[ckey].filter(child => m[ckey]
                                .find(mm => mm.key === (child.key || child.value)) &&
                                !o.find(c => (c.key || c.value) === (child.key || child.value))) : []), [])
                })
            )
        };
    };
    return { value: e[0].categories[0].key, label: e[0].categories[0].value,
        children: Object.values(_join(_get("companies"), _join(_get("brands"), _get("models"))))[0] };
});
```

---

It has 2 functions:

1. **_get()**
2. **_join()**

1. When calling `_get()` you pass as an argument the key you are searching. It can be `companies`, `brands`, `models`, etc. It returns an array with all the occurrences of the key's values you passed as argument. E.g.

```
    _get("companies")
```

returns

```
{
    "companies": [
        {
            "key": "apple",
            "value": "Apple"
        },
        {
            "key": "ibm",
            "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
            "key": "lenovo",
            "value": "Lenovo"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

2. The `_join()` function does the magic. It takes a parent group and a children group and transforms them in the format you want:

---

#### Here a working example

```js
const input = {
  "notebook": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "macbook",
        "value": "MacBook"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2021",
        "value": "2021"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "2021 Pro",
        "value": "2021 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "e590",
        "value": "E590"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "p1",
        "value": "P1"
      }]
    }
  ],
  "smartphone": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "11pro",
        "value": "11 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2020",
        "value": "2020"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "12",
        "value": "12"
      }]
    }
  ]
}

const out = Object.values(input).map(e => {
    const _get = key => ({ [key]: e.map(m => [...m[key]]).flat()
        .filter((m, i, a) => !a.slice(i + 1).find(c => c.key === m.key)) });
    const _join = (parent, children) => {
        const [pkey, ckey] = [Object.keys(parent)[0], Object.keys(children)[0]];
        return {
            [pkey]: parent[pkey].map(p => ({ value: p.key, label: p.value,
                    children: e.reduce((o, m) =>
                        o.concat(m[pkey].find(pp => pp.key === p.key) ?
                            children[ckey].filter(child => m[ckey]
                                .find(mm => mm.key === (child.key || child.value)) &&
                                !o.find(c => (c.key || c.value) === (child.key || child.value))) : []), [])
                })
            )
        };
    };
    return { value: e[0].categories[0].key, label: e[0].categories[0].value,
        children: Object.values(_join(_get("companies"), _join(_get("brands"), _get("models"))))[0] };
});

console.log(out);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Take into account that the Stack overflow snippet may omit some repeated objects. It would be better if you try it yourself**

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  "notebook": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "macbook",
        "value": "MacBook"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2021",
        "value": "2021"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "2021 Pro",
        "value": "2021 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "e590",
        "value": "E590"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "p1",
        "value": "P1"
      }]
    }
  ],
  "smartphone": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "11pro",
        "value": "11 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2020",
        "value": "2020"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "12",
        "value": "12"
      }]
    }
  ]
};

const transforemd = Object.entries(data).map(([product, data]) => {
    const item = {
      children: []
    };
    
    data.forEach(value => {
      item.value = value.categories?.[0].key;
      item.label = value.categories?.[0].value;
     
      value.companies?.forEach(company => {
        let sub = {
          value: company.key,
          label: company.value,
          children: []
        };
        let toFind = item.children.find(element => element.value === company.key);
        if (toFind) 
          sub = toFind;
        else 
          item.children.push(sub);
          
        value.brands?.forEach(brand => {
          let entry = {
            value: brand.key,
            label: brand.value,
            children: []
          };
          let toFind = sub.children.find(element => element.value === brand.key);
          
          if (toFind) 
            entry = toFind;
          else 
            sub.children.push(entry);
          
          value.models?.forEach(model => {
            let product = {
              value: model.key,
              label: model.value,
            };
            entry.children.push(product);
          });
        });
      });
    });
    
    
    return item;
});

console.log(transforemd);
```

Comment: Definitely helpful. Thanks ! Can this also be done by using Array.prototype. functionalities ? Maybe map or reduce ?

These normal for loops I really do not like

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp you can't use Array#map because the relation is not one-to-one. But definitely we can replace all for of s to Array#forEach. Updated!

Comment: I would use `reduce()`.

Comment: @AdamPatterson can you please describe a bit how can we use reduce?

Comment: @AmirMB Try reading the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

- First I would slightly change initial data:

```
mydata = [...mydata.notebook, ...mydata.smartphone];
```

This is the same as calling `Array.flat()` (only logically) and I am removing `notebook` and `smartphone` keys from the starting object, merging all nested objects in the same array. In fact, you do not need them, but you are only interested in `category`.

- The next part could be creating some utility methods, like:

```
function getOrCreateChild(children, entry) {
  let child = children.find(c => c.value === entry.key && c.label === entry.value);
  
  if (child === undefined) {
    child = {
      value: entry.key,
      label: entry.value,
      children: []
    }
    
    children.push(child);
  }
   
  return child;
}
```

You want to append a new child to `children` only if the visited key, which is considered as the pair `(value, label)`, does not exist yet.

The other one that contains the main logic is:

```
const hierarchyOrder = ["categories", "companies", "brands", "models"];
function fillNestedLevels(children, cur, hierarchyLevel) {
  if (hierarchyLevel === hierarchyOrder.length)
    return;
  
  const entryArray = cur[hierarchyOrder[hierarchyLevel]];
    
  for (const entry of entryArray) {
    let child = getOrCreateChild(children, entry);
    fillNestedLevels(child.children, cur, hierarchyLevel + 1);
  }
}
```

This method is called for each object (`cur`) in the initial array and its purpose is to fill the `children` array with entries at the correct level, which is determined by `hierarchyOrder[hierarchyLevel]`. In order to avoid duplicate children we use the method described before, that is `getOrCreateChild`.

Finally, the entrypoint is a `reduce` function that just calls the above method with the accumulator (that starts with an empty array) and an array element.

```
const result = mydata.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  fillNestedLevels(acc, cur, 0);
  return acc;
}, [])
```

---

All together:

```js
let mydata = {
  "notebook": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "macbook",
        "value": "MacBook"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2021",
        "value": "2021"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "2021 Pro",
        "value": "2021 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "e590",
        "value": "E590"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "notebook",
        "value": "Notebook"
      }],
      "companies": [{
          "key": "ibm",
          "value": "IBM"
        },
        {
          "key": "lenovo",
          "value": "Lenovo"
        }
      ],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "thinkpad",
        "value": "Thinkpad"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "p1",
        "value": "P1"
      }]
    }
  ],
  "smartphone": [{
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2019",
        "value": "2019"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "11pro",
        "value": "11 Pro"
      }]
    },
    {
      "categories": [{
        "key": "smartphone",
        "value": "Smartphone"
      }],
      "companies": [{
        "key": "apple",
        "value": "Apple"
      }],
      "brands": [{
        "key": "iphone",
        "value": "IPHONE"
      }],
      "modelYears": [{
        "key": "2020",
        "value": "2020"
      }],
      "models": [{
        "key": "12",
        "value": "12"
      }]
    }
  ]
}

mydata = [...mydata.notebook, ...mydata.smartphone];
const hierarchyOrder = ["categories", "companies", "brands", "models"];

function getOrCreateChild(children, entry) {
  let child = children.find(c => c.value === entry.key && c.label === entry.value);
  
  if (child === undefined) {
    child = {
      value: entry.key,
      label: entry.value,
      children: []
    }
    
    children.push(child);
  }
   
  return child;
}

function fillNestedLevels(children, cur, hierarchyLevel) {
  if (hierarchyLevel === hierarchyOrder.length)
    return;
  
  const entryArray = cur[hierarchyOrder[hierarchyLevel]];
    
  for (const entry of entryArray) {
    let child = getOrCreateChild(children, entry);
    fillNestedLevels(child.children, cur, hierarchyLevel + 1);
  }
}

const result = mydata.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  fillNestedLevels(acc, cur, 0);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

---

Some final thoughts:

- It seems a lot of code but is quite straightforward and easily maintainable. In this case I will discourage you to search for "one-line" solutions that might be really complex to understand for you and for your collegues.
- It is a quite flexible solution as well. If in the future you want to include `modelYears` you just have to append it to `hierarchyOrder`.
- For consistency, even the most nested objects have the `children` property. This is something you can control of course, but I guess that ignoring them would not make a difference.

Comment: Thx. can you neverthelss provide me the "complex" code ?

Comment: You should not ask someone to write worse code :) The point is: if I wanted to rewrite it, performances would not change but readability would decrease. Why would you want that?

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp Thanks for the bounty, sorry to say it but the accepted solution really has poor performances. I am not commenting the readability because it is subjective but If you use it in a production environment you are going to regret it.